# Is Lambert W Function in complex domain $(x+iy)e^{x+iy}=a+ib$ solvable?

Tags: special-functions, approximation, lambert-w

I am solving by method of approximation complex Lambert $W$ Function $(x+iy)e^{x+iy}=a+ib$ for $x$ and $y$, when real values of $a$ and $b$ are given and $i=\sqrt{-1}$. I want to know whether such type of function has been solved earlier. If answer is in affirmative, I pray, I may kindly be informed of its reference or any other source.

Comment: The Lambert $W$-function is a multivalued function. For a detailed discussion of the branches see [this](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf) paper.

Comment: We have $x=−iy+W(a+ib)$ and $y=ix-iW(a+ib)$. For $\alpha=a+ib$ and $\beta=x+iy$, we have $\beta=W(\alpha)$. Search Mathematics Stack Exchange, MathOverflow and the internet with Lambert* approximat* real for methods of approximation.

Comment: My question appeared in this forum, when I could not find using search engines any earlier work relating to solution to such function.

Comment: You need the inverse of $$c\frac{y}{1-\tan(y)}$$. If you transform $\tan$ into its $e^{it}$ form, then you could solve with [these series](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00138v2.pdf). If not, there are more papers like it. The author also is on this forum.

Comment: May you please write the equation and tell me which variable is to be evaluated? Regards.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know whether such type of function has been solved earlier.

It's been done before, for example it's implemented in [SciPy](https://scipy.org/).  If installed, you can access it from Python as `scipy.special.lambertw`.

> If answer is in affirmative, I pray, I may kindly be informed of its reference or any other source.

SciPy is available on GutHub.  The module providing Lambert $W$ is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/special/_lambertw.py

> **Possible issues**:
> The evaluation can become inaccurate very close to the branch point
> at $-1/e$. In some corner cases, `lambertw` might currently
> fail to converge, or can end up on the wrong branch.

The references given are Wikipedia and the PDF already linked before, [*"On the Lambert W function"*](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf) from Corless et al.

`_lambertw.py` is just a top-level Python interface, the very imlpementation is in Cython module [`_lambertw.pxd`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/special/_lambertw.pxd).

### The implementation basically goes like this:

1. Determine a starting value for [Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method). This is accomplished by an asymptotic expansion of $W$:$$W_k(z)\approx \log z + 2\pi ik - \log(\log z + 2\pi ik)$$ There are cases where a [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) is better, and thus used in such cases (branch $k=0$ around $z=0$). Around the branch point $z=-1/e$, yet another expansion is used.
2. Apply Halley's method until the desired accuracy  is reached: $$w \mapsto w - 
   \dfrac{we^w-z}{e^w(w+1) - \dfrac{(w+2)(we^w-z)}{2w+2}} $$Notice that the accuracy is an input to `lambertw`.

For details see the code resp. the document linked above and formulae (4.20), (4.22) and (5.9).

Answer (score 0):

*To stay with Lambert function.*

The equations to be solved are
$$-a-e^x y \sin (y)+e^x x \cos (y)=0 \tag 1$$
$$-b+e^x x \sin (y)+e^x y \cos (y)=0 \tag 2$$
Using $(1)$
$$x=W\left(a e^{-y \tan (y)} \sec (y)\right)+y \tan (y)\tag 3$$
Plug in $(2)$ and you need to solve numerically for $y$
$$\frac{a y \sec ^2(y)}{W\left(a e^{-y \tan (y)} \sec (y)\right)}+a \tan (y)-b=0 \tag 4$$

Trying with $a=\pi$ and $b=e$, Newton method gives
$$y=0.394401045253167$$ from which
$$x=1.194608982218346$$

Checking, the lhs is
$$3.14159265358979 + 2.71828182845905\,i$$

**Edit**

Discarding Lambert function  and using
$$x=\frac{a \cos (y)+b \sin (y)}{b \cos (y)-a \sin (y)}\,y$$ we need to find the zero of function
$$f(y)=\frac{y}{b \cos (y)-a \sin (y)} \exp\Bigg[\frac{a \cos (y)+b \sin (y)}{b \cos (y)-a \sin (y)} \,y\Bigg]-1\tag 5$$   which will have a solution between $0$ and $\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$.

Because of this *a priori* bkown upper bound, it could be interesting to let $y=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$ and to look for the zero of
$$G(t)={2 \left(t^2+1\right) \tan ^{-1}(t)}\,\,\exp\Bigg[2\frac{at^2-2bt-a }{bt^2+2at-b }\tan ^{-1}(t)\Bigg]+(b t^2+2 a t-b)\tag 6$$

and the solution will easily be bracketed before starting an iterative process.

$$\min \Bigg[0,\tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)\Bigg] < t_* <\max \Bigg[0,\tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)\Bigg] $$

Comment: $W$ has infinitely many branches.  How do you consistently select a specific branch?  With Newton-Raphson this is not easy because you don't know to which branch it converges &mdash; provided it converges at all. (There are cases where Newton-Raphson only converges to a finite cycle if you are not close enough to a zero.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts. I fully egree with you. I just wrote it that way to stay formal for illustrattion purposes. This is why I added my edit which shows that there is no problem.. By the way, you make me crazy every single time I have to type your usere name.  Cheers :-)

Comment: My question pertains to whether (x+iy)e^(x+iy) has been solved earlier. If it has been, please help me by informing its reference or other source. By the way, sir,  the equation between x and y derived by you is already known to me. It further requires elimination of x and  then numerical approximation of y. The numerical approximation I am attempting is unique and therefore I  need reference to earlier such work. I could not find it by search engines. Regards.

Comment: @NarinderWadhawan. Over the last 60+ years, I saw and produced myself extensions of Lambert function even in the complex domain for the generalized Lambert function (work done in my former reseach group). I do not know any  reference paper (we did not publish the thesis). I am curious to know your approximations since I made a few ones I did not add; can you tell if $(a,b)$ are positive and what are the ranges you cover ? I would interesting to cooperate (if you wish, for sure).

Comment: @Claude Leibovic  I could determine formula for approximation of x and y in equation (x+iy) e^(x+iy)=-a and crosschecked it assigning positive value to ‘a’ and it worked. I am going to check it by assigning values to ‘a’ from minus infinity to plus infinity and writing the iterated result in tabular form. For ten different values of ‘a’, it will be checked. On the same lines, formula for a +ib when a and b are non zero real but are not plus or minus infinity will be devised. Problems encountered will be suitably solved. Regards.